# I go round and round

Tags: riddle

> I go round and round
>   and rise above the ground
>   My head’s nothing but air
>   & lets anything fair
>   To make some gay
>   and others flay.

Who am I?

Comment: A hot air passenger balloon ? It fits moderately.

Comment: Has anyone answered correctly or is anyone even remotely close?

Answer (score 14):

You are the

> sun.

I go round and round

> the sun is perceived from the Earth as "going around".

and rise above the ground

> the sun rises in the morning.

My head’s nothing but air

> this is a metaphor. head=sun=helium=air

& lets anything fair

> (of the weather) become fine. Good weather.

To make some gay

> Rainbow, as commented by Will.

and others flay.

> to get sunburn.

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> The water cycle?

I go round and round

> It does

and rise above the ground

> The cloud stage

My head’s nothing but air

> The 'head' is the top which is the clouds which are composed of air and water

& lets anything fair

> Not sure if this is a clue?

To make some gay

> When it rains it can create rainbows, which as @Will points out is the sign of gay pride

and others flay.

> Rocks weathering and being eroded, being 'flayed'

Comment: Rainbows are gay.

Comment: I have heard gay means happy as well in quite a few places.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer-

> Balloon

I go round and round

> Increases in size when filled with air and is round.

and rise above the ground

> when filled with helium or fly in wind.

My head’s nothing but air

> Filled with air and balloon looks like head.

& lets anything fair
To make some gay
and others flay.

> Used in celebrations..

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Life cycle?

I go round and round

> yes, It go round and round

and rise above the ground

> multicellular stages

My head’s nothing but air

> air is most important part of life cycle

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

> the smoke of a cigarette, that rise over the ground and becomes air

You make some gay

> if they like to smoke

and others flay

> if they don't like somebody smokes near them!

Answer (score 0):

You are a:

> Hot air balloon

I go round and round

> We can travel from one place to another.

and rise above the ground

> It starts from the ground and fly into the air.

My head’s nothing but air

> A hot air balloon of a bag called the envelope that is capable of containing heated air.So its head contains only air.

lets anything fair

> Used in science fair.

To make some gay

> Represents color of Rainbow.

[image]

and others flay

> flay means to beat or whip (someone or something) in a very violent and severe way. The hot air balloon beats the air(atmosphere) while travelling.

Comment: I suppose I added it as a comment before you answered.

Comment: Before i have seen your comment, i have that answer in my mind..

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

> An Amusement Park Ride

I go round and round
and rise above the ground

> Most amusement park rides do just that going round and round, rising above the ground and going back to where they started.

My head’s nothing but air

> Reference about the passengers going at high speeds with the wind in their heads.

& lets anything fair

> Reference about the fact that fairs often have amusement park rides.

To make some gay

> Gay also means happy which the amusement park ride can definitely contribute to.

and others flay.

> Riding in amusement park rides can also cause you to fill ill and whip you around in your seat.